# TFS API C#: issue to get work items

Tags: c#, tfs

I use TFS API through C#.
I need to modify work item that attached to particular change set, however I can not see iny information about work item.

```
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
```

My `workItemStore` is always `null`:

[image]

Furthermore, my code:

```
 // Connect to server
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ConstTfsServerUri));
        tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);
        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        // Create versionspec's. Example start with changeset 529
        //VersionSpec versionFrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("463450", null);
        //VersionSpec versionFrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("400000", null);
        VersionSpec versionFrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C529", null);
        // If you want all changesets use this versionFrom:
        // VersionSpec versionFrom = null;
        VersionSpec versionTo = VersionSpec.Latest;

        // Get Changesets
        var changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(
            serverPath,
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            0,
            RecursionType.Full,
            null,
            versionFrom,
            versionTo,
            //Int32.MaxValue,
            200,
            true,
            false
            ).Cast<Changeset>().ToList();
```

returns exception in property `WorkItems` for each changeset object's instance:

[image]

My references are:

[image]
Maybe I've forgot to add an essential reference?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: it was in references for sure!
When I created a new solution, copied exactly the same code and used NuGet package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, issue was resolved:
[image]
And property `WorkItems` in changeset objects instances have value with no exception:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need specify the TeamProjectCollection in your code:

```
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://pttfs1:8080/tfs/collectionname"));
```

Comment: It works without definition the name of collection.
This path "http://pttfs1:8080/tfs/" works perfect.

Comment: Yet i would recommend to dynamically get the tfs server url, just in case in the future you would change serverurl